# Apache unable to start Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have been trying to setup a Rails application in `RHEL 7` using `Apache (v 2.4.6), Phusion Passenger (v 5.3.5)`.

Everything works fine without SSL configuration.

But if I set up virtualhost for 443 port, I get the following error after restarting (`service httpd restart`) the Apache service.

```
[Wed Nov 07 18:20:50.215257 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31701] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully

[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.2344 31732/T7 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:641 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.2344 31732/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1216 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.2345 31732/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1117 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 3793, application /opt/apps/my_rails_app (production)
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.2347 31732/T9 Ser/Server.h:903 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.2347 31732/T9 Ser/Server.h:559 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.2348 31732/T7 Ser/Server.h:903 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.2348 31732/T7 Ser/Server.h:559 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.2349 31732/Tc Ser/Server.h:903 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.2349 31732/Tc Ser/Server.h:559 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.2349 31732/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1117 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 3793, application /opt/apps/my_rails_app (production)
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.4769 31732/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1295 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.5469 4216/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1300 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.5688 4219/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1310 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.5689 4219/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.5754 4219/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:985 ]: Passenger core online, PID 4219
[Wed Nov 07 18:20:51.576671 2018] [suexec:notice] [pid 4214] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)

[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.5800 4219/T7 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:641 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.5800 4219/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1216 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.5801 4219/T7 Ser/Server.h:903 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.5801 4219/T7 Ser/Server.h:559 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.5802 4219/Tb Ser/Server.h:903 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.5802 4219/Tb Ser/Server.h:559 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.5802 4219/Ta Ser/Server.h:903 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.5802 4219/Ta Ser/Server.h:559 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[Wed Nov 07 18:20:51.598254 2018] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 4214] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.6198 4237/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1300 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.6221 4219/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1295 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.6448 4240/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1310 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.6449 4240/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:51.6517 4240/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:985 ]: Passenger core online, PID 4240
[Wed Nov 07 18:20:51.653813 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 4214] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Nov 07 18:20:51.658584 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4214] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) Phusion_Passenger/5.3.5 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 07 18:20:51.658612 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4214] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[ N 2018-11-07 18:20:54.1476 4240/T5 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:517 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
```

I did not find any particular error message from the logs as above.
Looking forward to your help.

Thanks

**EDIT 1**

On the web page, I get `Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

`ssl_error_log` shows the following error:

```
[Wed Nov 07 19:02:46.529549 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 14038] [client 138.35.142.252:35811] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /opt/apps/my_rails_app/public/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

SSL conf file (ssl.conf) looks as below:

```
 <Directory "/opt/apps/my_rails_app/public">
    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
 PassengerAppEnv production
 PassengerAppRoot "/opt/apps/my_rails_app/public"
 PassengerHighPerformance on
```

Comment: What error?  What configuration did you setup?  Is it the "No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor"?  If it is, search here, this is frequent.

Comment: @Nic3500 Please check the EDIT section of the question

Comment: When you access a site without specifying a web page, Apache will look at the `DirectoryIndex` value to find the default file to send to the client.  So somewhere in your configuration, you probably have `DirectoryIndex index.html` or similar.  The directory must have an "index.html" file with proper permissions.